# Get css value with pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get element width or height value which would be translated as a pixel number? All I got by using `.css('width')` are the expressions, not even a percentage number, like `calc(-25px + 50%)`.

**Edit**

my code here. (Chrome)

```
var bars_width = element.css('width');
$('.histgram-content').css('width', bars_width);
bars_width = parseInt(bars_width.replace('px', '')) * 0.85;
$('.histgram-bar').css('width', (bars_width/data.length).toFixed(0).toString() + 'px');
/*** average Y ***/
var graph_height = $('.histgram-graph').css('height');
graph_height = parseInt(graph_height.replace('px', ''));

var average_height = $('.average-line').css('top');
average_height = graph_height - parseInt(average_height.replace('px', ''));
```

The `average_height` returns the expression I said. The last line got the result of 'NaN'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of jQuery's dimension related methods:

- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width)
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height)
- [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth)
- [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight)

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2d1m4pxv/)

Comment: I don't know why this is not working for me, and how about other css values like 'top'? I tried .css('top'), it directly returned the expression.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Seeing your actual code would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use window.getComputedStyle(),example:
window.getComputedStyle($('div'))['width']

Answer (score 0):

You can height

```
$('#element-id').height();
```

You can width

```
$('#element-id').width();
```

Comment: returns percentage value. I need pixel values